Jupyter Notebook markdown cell or text is not visible when I run that cell
I am new to Jupyter Notebook. I am using it on Anaconda. When I put some markdown text, it is all good:

But once I hit shift + enter, it just disappears:

But when I just randomly click on the location, the cell becomes visible but with much less height:

What should I do to fix the issue? I couldn't find anything online that could solve my issue.
